# Como expressar um predicado de não igualdade em Java?

Tags: java, expressões-lambda, java-8

Tenho a seguinte expressão:

```java
final String idStatusAutorizada = ...; // valor constante
return pendencias.stream()
    .map(TipoBlocCarga::getIdStatus)
    .anyMatch(idStatusPendencia -> !idStatusAutorizada.equals(idStatusPendencia));
```

Porém o último *lambda* não está me satisfazendo esteticamente. Gostaria de transformar em alguma espécie de referência de método. Outra alternativa que não me agrada é declarar uma variável com o predicado de `idStatusAutorizada::equals` e passar o método para a função desse predicado com [`negate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html#negate--), mas devo dizer que me aparenta ainda não estar suficientemente elegante:

```java
final String idStatusAutorizada = ...; // valor constante
Predicate<String> equalsAutorizada = idStatusAutorizada::equals;
return pendencias.stream()
    .map(TipoBlocCarga::getIdStatus)
    .anyMatch(equalsAutorizada.negate());
```

> Eu acharia lindo se fosse possível fazer `idStatusAutorizada::equals.negate()`, mas o Java 8 não permite isso. Não sei se isso mudou nas versões mais recentes, mas eu não posso alterar a versão do Java no meu código por conta das plataformas em que o código será executado.

Então, meu questionamento: é possível fazer um predicado de não igualdade em Java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sup>*As soluções abaixo são um compilado das respostas [desta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21488056).*</sup>

---

Se você quer usar o *method reference* **e** não quer criar uma variável só para guardar o `Predicate`, até dá para fazer. Só não é tão "bonito" quanto você gostaria, pois envolve fazer um *cast* do *method reference* para `Predicate`, assim é possível chamar o método `negate`:

```
return pendencias.stream()
    .map(TipoBlocCarga::getIdStatus)
    .anyMatch(((Predicate<String>) idStatusAutorizada::equals).negate());
```

<sup>Talvez tenha ficado até mais "feio" que as suas alternativas...</sup>

---

A partir do Java 11, existe o método estático [`Predicate.not`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Predicate.html#not(java.util.function.Predicate)), para o qual você pode passar diretamente o *method reference*:

```
return pendencias.stream()
    .map(TipoBlocCarga::getIdStatus)
    .anyMatch(Predicate.not(idStatusAutorizada::equals));
```

Mas se você está usando Java < 11, existe ainda a possibilidade de criar um método parecido:

```
public static <T> Predicate<T> not(Predicate<T> predicate) {
    return predicate.negate();
}

...
return pendencias.stream()
    .map(TipoBlocCarga::getIdStatus)
    .anyMatch(not(idStatusAutorizada::equals));
```

Comment: Não se pode dizer que o Java não se tem esforçado por evoluir xD. Esse ultimo mesmo sem o Java 11 ficou ótimo a nivel de legibilidade.